# LocationManager's location in Android returns null

Tags: java, android, location, locationmanager

I'm testing my Android app on a device, and it always fails when I use

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

However, if I use NETWORK_PROVIDER instead of GPS_PROVIDER, it works. The currentLocation returns null.

How can I handle this? Is there anything specific I need to put in my locationListener?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GPS_PROVIDER may not work in bounded place, suppose inside a house or something like this. You should program it in such a way that if gps provider gives null location then you use network provider as a alternative although its accuracy is not so high. 
Here there is another issue. Your code should be as follows:

```
     if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
{
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}
```

Comment: It is enabled then also giving null

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check that the GPS icon on device status bar has stopped blinking, marking you actually have GPS lock.

The call returns null if the location is not currently known, for example if you lack GPS lock.

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically securing GPS lock?

Comment: GPS lock means the device has acquired the location successfully from the GPS satellites. So, when you ask for GPS location the device starts connecting to satellites and it takes some amount of time, and might not succeed at all if you are indoors.

I recommend you use the existing GPS-enabled applications on your phone before rushing in to develop on it, to get basic understanding on how GPS works.